# Numpy assignment behaviour

Tags: python, numpy

`b` is

```
array([-0.06106568, -0.10843541, -0.0694688 ,  0.02464023, -0.03686665,
       -0.0582096 , -0.13476669, -0.08505708,  0.00391955, -0.12300518,
       -0.01183732, -0.05374973, -0.12300518, -0.05312849,  0.01963862,
        0.00155719, -0.10843541, -0.08490177, -0.08505708, -0.02026149,
       -0.01777489,  0.01183732, -0.11575136,  0.04278603, -0.0694688 ,
       -0.06106568, -0.08755022, -0.01660802, -0.06087603, -0.06582411])

a = b
a[a <= 0] = 0
a[a > 0] = 1
```

With the code above I would like to replace elements in a, but b also  changes... Could you please explain me where is the mistake?

Comment: Well you assigned a named ref `a` to `b` with `a=b`, if you wanted a copy then `a = np.copy(b)` would give you a copy

Comment: I would like to make a copy...sorry I am new in python

Answer (score 3):

By using expression `a = b` you actually copy the reference to `b`. If you want to copy its value, you should rather walk through all `b`'s items and copy their values to `a`.

In numpy you should use `copy` function.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> b = numpy.array([-0.06106568, -0.10843541, -0.0694688 ,  0.02464023, -0.03686665,
...        -0.0582096 , -0.13476669, -0.08505708,  0.00391955, -0.12300518,
...        -0.01183732, -0.05374973, -0.12300518, -0.05312849,  0.01963862,
...         0.00155719, -0.10843541, -0.08490177, -0.08505708, -0.02026149,
...        -0.01777489,  0.01183732, -0.11575136,  0.04278603, -0.0694688 ,
...        -0.06106568, -0.08755022, -0.01660802, -0.06087603, -0.06582411])
>>> a = numpy.copy(b)
>>> a
array([-0.06106568, -0.10843541, -0.0694688 ,  0.02464023, -0.03686665,
       -0.0582096 , -0.13476669, -0.08505708,  0.00391955, -0.12300518,
       -0.01183732, -0.05374973, -0.12300518, -0.05312849,  0.01963862,
        0.00155719, -0.10843541, -0.08490177, -0.08505708, -0.02026149,
       -0.01777489,  0.01183732, -0.11575136,  0.04278603, -0.0694688 ,
       -0.06106568, -0.08755022, -0.01660802, -0.06087603, -0.06582411])
>>> a[a<= 0] = 0
>>> a[a> 0] = 1
>>> a
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
>>> b
array([-0.06106568, -0.10843541, -0.0694688 ,  0.02464023, -0.03686665,
       -0.0582096 , -0.13476669, -0.08505708,  0.00391955, -0.12300518,
       -0.01183732, -0.05374973, -0.12300518, -0.05312849,  0.01963862,
        0.00155719, -0.10843541, -0.08490177, -0.08505708, -0.02026149,
       -0.01777489,  0.01183732, -0.11575136,  0.04278603, -0.0694688 ,
       -0.06106568, -0.08755022, -0.01660802, -0.06087603, -0.06582411])
```

There are some native ways to do it, but if you work with mathematics, using only numpy is strongly recommended.

**UPDATE**

I don't have in my mind any non-numpy way which will cause entire compatibility with your case.

Comment: What do you mean by "native ways" to do it ?

Comment: `a=list(b)` makes `a` a python list so the rest of the code wouldn't work as `a[a<= 0]` only makes sense with numpy arrays ...

Comment: I'm still a bit puzzled as to why you would not want to use numpy's copy when you are already working with numpy arrays ...

Answer (score 1):

When you did `a=b` then you made a named ref to `b` so `a` and `b` were views on the same object, if you wanted a copy then use `np.copy`:

```
In [35]:
a = np.copy(b)
a[a<= 0] = 0
a[a> 0] = 1
a

Out[35]:
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])

In [36]:
b

Out[36]:
array([-0.06106568, -0.10843541, -0.0694688 ,  0.02464023, -0.03686665,
       -0.0582096 , -0.13476669, -0.08505708,  0.00391955, -0.12300518,
       -0.01183732, -0.05374973, -0.12300518, -0.05312849,  0.01963862,
        0.00155719, -0.10843541, -0.08490177, -0.08505708, -0.02026149,
       -0.01777489,  0.01183732, -0.11575136,  0.04278603, -0.0694688 ,
       -0.06106568, -0.08755022, -0.01660802, -0.06087603, -0.06582411])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually just pointing a to b, that both contain the same list. Essentially python variables are names that are given to objects. You want to create a new object containing the new list here. You have many options:

You could use the built-in `list()` function:

```
a = list(b)
```

Or you could import `copy` and use that.

```
import copy
a = copy.copy(b)
```

or in the case of numpy:

```
import numpy
a = np.copy(b)
```

Comment: Note that `a` and `b` are numpy arrays not lists.